# Variable passed to multiple threads of the same function

Tags: python, webhooks, python-multithreading

I am currently working on a system that sends webhooks to multiple Discord using dhooks.

This is the function used to call the function which sends the webhooks. The length of `webhooks` is 2 and it's a list of lists.

```
for hook in webhooks:
    thread.start_new_thread(send_hook,(hook, embed, tag))
```

This is the send_hook function:

```
def send_hook(hook, embed, tag):

    embed.set_footer(text="{} x Will".format(hook[0])) <-- This is the part where the error happens

    webhook = Webhook(hook[1])
    webhook.send(embed=embed)
```

The error I am getting is, when I set the footer in line 2 of `send_hook`,  the variable inserted into the embed variable is sometimes sent to the wrong webhooks - almost as if its being over ridden.

As an example:

This is my list webhooks: `[["Webhook 1 text", "discordwebhook1"], ["Webhook 2 text", "discordwebhook1"]]`.

What will happen is that in the channel of `discordwebhook1` the footer will say "Webhook 1 text", but in the channel of `discordwebhoo2` the footer will say "Webhook 1 text" as-well.

I have tried creating a new variable of the embed in the `send_hook` function - however this also didn't work (code below).

```
def send_hook(hook, embed, tag):
    new_embed = embed
    new_embed.set_footer(text="{} x Will".format(hook[0])) <-- This is the part where the error happens

    webhook = Webhook(hook[1])
    webhook.send(embed=new_embed)
```

I appreciate all help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get 'embed'? Notice that 'embed' and 'tag' are always passed to every newly created thread, you need to do a deepcopy of each if necessary

```
from copy import deepcopy

for hook in webhooks:
    thread.start_new_thread(send_hook,(hook, deepcopy(embed), tag))
```

Comment: Hey there! So embed is the same when sent to every thread of the send_hook function, however embed is changed within the send_hook function and for each thread, the value its changed to is different.

Comment: If you are just modifying the endpoint of the webhook to send off a webhook once and then you will discard the webhook object you created and end the thread, this solution should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Two threads have access to the same variable, and they are both modifying the variable. The outcome of your program depends on which one reaches the code that changes the variable first.

There are two possible solutions, depending on how you want the problem to be resolved:

1. **If you don't need all threads to share the same value**, or if the object is small and cheap to copy, make a copy of the variable you are passing before you pass it, by passing `deepcopy(embed)` instead of `embed` - see [the solution posted by @user1438644](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309927/463213) for code.
2. **If you want all threads to share the same value**, or if it is expensive to make copies of the object, you will need to create a lock with `my_lock = threading.Lock()`, and when you get to the race condition part of your program (i.e., the part that modifies the shared variable), surround it with a context manager `with my_lock:`, which acquires the lock at the start and returns the lock when finished. For example:

```py
import threading
my_lock = threading.Lock()

# your code here

for hook in webhooks:
    threading.Thread(send_hook, args=(hook, embed, tag))

# more code here

def send_hook(hook, embed, tag):
    # Ensure embed is only changed by one thread at a time
    with my_lock:
        print("Lock acquired")
        embed.set_footer(text="hello world")
        webhook = Webhook(hook[1])
        webhook.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I've tried the first option, however that didnt fix the problem. Is there a `lock` for the _thread library

Comment: Do you have a link to the `thread` python module you're using? There's probably an `acquire_lock()` function or something similar. You can try `dir(thread)` (if `thread` is the name of the module you are using).